# To support loadbalancing on NodeJS Server where do we keep our database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add the load balancing on GCP, my doubt is where shall I keep my database (MySql). Does it have to be on different VM. where all the scaled VM are accessing it.

If I install it on the same VM where my NodeJS server is running after scaling my data will be scattered in multiple database in multiple VM.

[image]

Is it the correct architecture to start the loading balancing on GCP

Comment: Server administration belongs to server fault. This is off topic here. But I'd chip in by saying that your schema is looking good. Until you create a cluster for mysql itself

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, yes you will want to keep your mysql datbase on a separate VM. This will come in handy if you decide to migrate, cluster etc your database. Also this is best if you are storing sessions in your database.